# How to secure licensekey generation

Tags: .net, encryption

Scenario, simplified for brevity:

A developer creates an application for a customer. The customer sells this app to end-users. The app requires a license key to run, and this key is generated by the customer for each end-user with a simple tool created by the developer. The license key contains an expiry date for the license and is encrypted so the end-user can’t tamper with it.

The problem here is that the developer (or anybody who has a copy of the license key generator) can easily create valid license keys. Should this generator fall into the wrong hands, it could spell disaster for the customers business.

Ideally, the customer would have to use a password to create new license keys. And this password would be unknown to the developer, and somehow baked into the decryption algorithm in the application so it will fail if an attempt to use an unauthorized key is made.

How would you implement a solution for this problem that is both transparent and secure?

Answer (score 2):

Public/Private key pairs used to generate and read the license key.

As per [Need advice to design 'crack-proof' software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383921/need-advice-to-design-crack-proof-software/2384059#2384059) it still doesn't give you complete protection.